# Calculated column "Running total" doesn't work when filtering

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with columns

`| Time | IP | Delta |`

I want to create a running total over Delta, so I create a column:

```
Running total =
VAR currentTime = [Time]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( [Delta] ),
        Connections[Time] <= currentTime,
        Connections
    )
```

It seems to work properly, but doesn't react to filtering by IP. This way my filtered table starts at 5 instead of 0, because delta for other IPs sums up to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Calculated columns** and calculated tables are different from measures since they **are static**: You can filter them, but they don't recalculate on filter changes.

Use this measure instead:

```
Delta running total in Time = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Connections'[Delta]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Connections'[Time]),
        ISONORAFTER('Connections'[Time], MAX('Connections'[Time]), DESC)
    )
)
```

Note: You can use the **Quick measure** "Running total" to let Power BI create the formula for you.